# form_tag not going to correct controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to create a simple form in a blog edit view that will just take in an id number and pass that through to the controller method. In my veiw I have

```
<div class = ''>
  <h4><%= _("Foo blog") %></h4>
    <ul id='foo' class='inputs-list'>
      <%= form_tag foo_path, :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= label_tag(:fooid, "Blog ID") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:fooid) %>
        <%= submit_tag("submit foo") %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I want clicking "submit foo" to submit the ID to the foo action in the controller.

In my controller I have:

```
def foo
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { 
      if params[:fooid]
        redirect_to '/'
      else
        redirect_to '/'
      end
    }
  end
end
```

And when I run rake routes I get:

```
 foo        /admin/content/foo(.:format)     {:controller=>"admin/content", :action=>"foo"}
```

But every time I click submit foo it doesn't get to that method and instead behaves as if I was trying to save the blog article. How do I get the form to redirect to the foo action in the admin/content controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the #Foo action to your routes?

You likely have something similar to:    `resources :admins`, and should change it to

```
resources :admins do
    resources :contents do
        member do
            post 'foo'
        end
    end
end
```

More information available at the [Rails Routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: So weirdly I can't find that anywhere. I'm working with legacy code so I didn't write any of this, but I'll see if I can find some way to make this help